# Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400] when uploading images

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I got this Error message when uploading images.  [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [400]

I have List images trying to upload to endpoint. There is a problem with my request as it has not reach the api.

```
Future<CommonResult> sendImagesToServer(String pid) async {
    dio.Dio d = dio.Dio();
    List<dio.MultipartFile> imageList = <dio.MultipartFile>[];

    for (File asset in imageFileList) {
      List<int> imageData = await asset.readAsBytes(); 

      dio.MultipartFile multipartFile =  dio.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        imageData,
        filename: 'load_image',
        contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
      );

      imageList.add(multipartFile);
      print("图片数据：$imageData");
    }

    dio.FormData formData = dio.FormData.fromMap({
      "pid": pid,
      "text": "text",
      "multipartFiles": imageList
    });
    String url = Constant.POST_IMAGES;
    var response = await d.post(url, data: formData);
    print(response);
    if (!response.data["authenticated"]) {
      return CommonResult.unauthorized();
    } else if (response.data["success"]) {
      print(response.data);
      Map<String, dynamic> map = {
        "data": response.data["data"],
      };
      return CommonResult.success(map, "success");
    } else {
      return CommonResult.failed();
    }
  }
```

Please, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you give more context about **it has not reach the api**, pls?

Comment: may be you reach the api but the image size exceed the limit for this api , try to use small size images.

Comment: The error was as you rightly stated the size of the data that exceeded the maximum size that my server could permit.